# Java.NIO InvalidIndexException - how to read and write with random access to large files

Tags: java, nio

I've created a `java.nio.MappedByteBuffer` around a `java.io.RandomAccessFile` (a file which is only 54 KB in size). The resulting `MappedByteBuffer` has a "capacity" and "limit" of around 12 KB, so when I try to invoke `mybytebuffer.get(i > 13044)` or `mybytebuffer.put(i > 13044, value)` it throws an `InvalidIndexException`.

All of this behavior is documented in Sun's official javadocs. My question is how I can use `java.nio ByteBuffers` to read or write anywhere in the file (I need random access). I can't seem to find an example or documentation of Java NIO that illustrates non-sequential access.

Comment: have you tried calling limit(the actual size)?

Comment: Yeah, but I can't set limit > capacity. Capacity is a hard limit that can't be increased. I was hoping that I could hide the fact that a ByteBuffer was wrapped around a file to the code that uses it, but it seems impossible to me now: there are no native solutions and you can't extend ByteBuffer to make your own abstraction.

Ugly.

Comment: Why bother with memory mapped file for a 54KB file? Memory mapping has  its advantages for large files. For small files, it is often slower as the initialization of the mapping takes some time.

Comment: The 54 KB file is just a test for my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MappedByteBuffer` can access files randomly...it is a 'direct byte buffer'.  (Specifically, it uses the OS's virtual memory subsystem to map the file to memory.)

You can access bytes randomly as in the code snippet here:

```
public void doIt() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    File file = new File("myfile");
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
    FileChannel fc = raf.getChannel();      
    MappedByteBuffer mbb = fc.map(MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, file.length());

    //get a random byte
    byte b1 = mbb.get(SOME_RANDOM_BYTE); 

    //get another random byte
    mbb.position(SOME_OTHER_BYTE_POSITION);
    byte b2 = mbb.get();
}
```

You can move about the MBB and access bytes (both reading and writing) as you need to.

Comment: +1. works as long as the file.length() is less than Integer.MAX_INT.

Comment: I seem to be getting a NonWriteableChannelException using this; I'll look into it.

Comment: If you use a FileInputStream, the channel isn't writeable. If you use a FileOutputStream, the channel isn't readable. Use a RandomAccessFile to produce a channel that is both readable and writeable.

Comment: @Jason Knight: good catch, I have modified my answer.  (Learn something new every day!)

Answer (score -1):

MappedByteBuffers do not themselves offer random access. This is a misunderstanding. Use a SeekableByteChannel for random access.

Comment: FileChannel (suggested in the selected answer) is the only implementing class of SeekableByteChannel: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/SeekableByteChannel.html